# compiz errors when restarting unity

Tags: unity, compiz

So I've been having problems with unity/compiz specifically 3 errors/warnings that I cannot get fixed:

1. compiz(decor) - Warn: no default decoration found, placement will not be correct
2. Error: unity.glib-gio :0 g_file_monitor_set_rate_limit: assertion 'G_IS_FILE_MONITOR (monitor)' failed
3. unity.session.gnome GnomeSessionManager.cpp:297 Gnome Session call failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

If I could get help with any of these it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have another desktop environment installed? You tagged this [tag:unity] *and* [tag:gnome]. If you have installed gnome, purge it, use `apt-get autoremove` and reboot. Gnome sometimes breaks Unity.

Comment: That was a default tag from stackexchange that I added by accident going to remove it.  I have not installed gnome desktop environement.